# How to get the Selected ID from DropDownList selection changed from View to Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a `DropDownList` in my View and I want to capture the ID of the selected value from both the `DropDownList` and pass that value as an argument in one of my Controller action method.

```
@Html.DropDownList("ddlL", new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "Select")
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#ddlL").empty();
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '@Url.Action("LoadLDet")',
                    datatype: 'JSON',
                    success: function (data) {
                        $("#ddlL").append('<option value=' + '0' + '>' + 'Select' + '</option>');

                        $.each(data, function (key, value) {

                            $("#ddlL").append('<option value=' + value.LId + '>' + value.LName + '</option>');
                        });
                    },
                    error: function (ex) {
                        alert('Failed to display Data');
                    }
                });
$("#ddlL").change(function () {
                $("#ddlW").empty();
                var LID=$(this).val();
                alert(LID);
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetWTest")',
                    datatype: 'JSON',
                    data: { LocID: $("#ddlL").val() },
                    success: function (data) {

                    $("#ddlW").append('<option value=' + '0' + '>' + 'Select' + '</option>');

                    $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                        $("#ddlW").append('<option value=' + value.WinId + '>' + value.WinName + '</option>');
                    });
                },
                error: function (ex) {
                    alert('Failed to load Win data');
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
</script>
```

Here With the help of `LoadLDet()` I am getting all the data and binding it in first `DropDownList` **ddlL**. And then passing the **LocID** getting from Change Event function of `DropDownList` **ddlL** to `JsonResult GetWin()` to bind the data of second `DropDownList` **ddlW**.

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult LoadLDet()
    {
        MyService.ServiceInfoClient Service = new MyService.ServiceInfoClient();
        var Loc = Service.GetLocList();
        return Json(Loc);
    }

public JsonResult GetWin(string LocID)
        {
            MyService.ServiceInfoClient Obj = new MyService.ServiceInfoClient();
            IEnumerable<MyService.Win> Win = Obj.GetWinByLocId(Convert.ToInt32(LocID));
            return Json(Win);
        }
```

I have another `ActionResult ExportDataInExcel()` class in which I want to pass selected `DropDownList` items **LId** and **WId** as argument in one of the method which I am calling to get data which needs to be exported. Please guide me how I can pass **"LId"** from view to controller which I am capturing in the Ajax also how can I pass **WId** i.e. the second `DropDownList` ID from View to below mentioned Action Method.

```
public ActionResult ExportDataInExcel()
        {
            ExportData(LId, WId, xyz);
            return View("Index");
        }
```

Comment: What's not working? What have you tried? All this code does it pull data from the server. You have nothing that even attempts to send anything back, so it's unclear what you even want to happen.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Yes I am getting the data in my `DropDownList` selection change but I don't know how to pass only LId from the Ajax in my ActionResult. That is why I need help.

Comment: Show as your `LoadLDet` action please.

Comment: @Spectarion I have updated the contents in my question would you like to have a look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this code. I used `data` to list all of the parameters that I want to send to server. I modified your code. I used `getJSON` method to fetch the JSON from the server. It's a little bit simpler.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#ddlL").empty();

    // Get data from LoadLDet action.
    $.getJSON('@Url.Action("LoadLDet")', function(data) {
        $("#ddlL").append('<option value="0">Select</option>');

        $.each(data, function (key, value) {
            $("#ddlL").append('<option value=' + value.LId + '>' + value.LName + '</option>');
        });
    });

    // Send data to ExportDataInExcel action.
    $("#ddlL").on('change', function() {
        var lId = $(this).val();
        var wId = $("#otherDropdownId").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("ExportDataInExcel")',
            datatype: 'json',
            data: {
                LId: lId, // FIRST DROPDOWN VALUE
                WId: wId  // SECOND DROPDOWN VALUE
            },
            success: function (data) {
                alert("Data successfuly sent.");
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Error occured while sending the data.");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Your action that receives parameter.

```
public ActionResult ExportDataInExcel(int LId, int WId)
{
    ExportData(LId, WId, xyz);
    return View("Index");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am sure the solution which you have given above will surely work but my problem is I am already using different ActionMethod in the URL of ddlL change function of Ajax. It means I have two DropDownList in my View. In the ddlL change event I am loading my second DropDownList ddlW. And I want to use the ID I am getting from both the DropDownList's to use in the ActionResult ExportDataInExcel().
Anything you can suggest?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. You want to achieve something like selecting a country and a city from the selected country. If I choose, France for example, next Dropdown will change its cities to only cities from France. Am I right?

Comment: Yes exactly I have achieved that. But now I want to pass the ID of the Data selected in both the `DropDownList` without submitting the form and ID's I am already having in my Ajax, and now I want to pass these two ID's in to my `ExportDataInExcel()` Action method. Do I have to write another Javascript Function and then in **URL** Do I have to mention my Controller Action Method i.e. `ExportDataInExcel()` ??

Comment: I updated my answer. Make sure to modify `var wId = $("#otherDropdownId").val();` to match your other dropdown ID.

Answer (score 0):

this can help

```
$("#ddlL").on('change', function() {
        var id =$(this).val(); // here's your value
        alert(id); // show your value
        // do your ajax call here
    });
```